# Entity Framework Code First migration issues -- Dataloss

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I've read every blog-post and MSDN articles(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) on code first migration but I am little unclear how I should use it.

Here is the Migration history on my project:

1. Initially I use `Enable-Migrations`, then `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database`.
2. I deployed the project
3. I made some minor changes to the model. rerun `add-migration` and `update-database`.
4. deployed the project
5. I added more attributes to the mode. Also, I run `Disable-Migrations` and run `Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigration`
6. Now when I deploy the project.. and run the app for the first time, **all the existing data is gone**

**Old Project (step #4) -- Migrations\Configurations.cs**

```
namespace POC_Manager.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<POC_Manager.Models.POC_ManagerContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            ContextKey = "POC_Manager.Models.POC_ManagerContext";
        }

        protected override void Seed(POC_Manager.Models.POC_ManagerContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
        }
    }
}
```

**New Project (step #6) -- Migrations\Configurations.cs**

```
namespace POC_Manager.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<POC_Manager.Models.POC_ManagerContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            ContextKey = "POC_Manager.Models.POC_ManagerContext";
        }

        protected override void Seed(POC_Manager.Models.POC_ManagerContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
        }
    }
}
```

**Old Project (step #4) -- Output from Get-Migrations**

> PM> Get-Migrations
>   Retrieving migrations that have been applied to the target database.
>   201405271907443_AutomaticMigration
>   201404252210039_InitialCreate

**New Project (step #6) -- Output from Get-Migrations**

> PM> Get-Migrations
>   Retrieving migrations that have been applied to the target database.
>   201407022020263_AutomaticMigration
>   201406262227296_AutomaticMigration
>   201405271907443_AutomaticMigration
>   201404252210039_InitialCreate
>   PM>

Another confusing part is that... Do I still need to run the Update-Database command after enabling automatic migrations ??

Answer (score 1):

Automatic Migrations are for automatically generating migration files based on changes to your classes; you will still need to run Update-Database unless you build logic for it into an initialization strategy.

As far as your data loss, it's most likely based on the initialization strategy that you used. I would suggest that you stick with CreateDatabaseIfNotExists unless your project really needs a custom initializer; the other standard ones are not terribly useful outside of an (early) development environment.